# RestKit Pagination

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm stuck with a pagination issue.

When I go to /?PageSize=:perPage&Page=:page" I will get a json response like this:

[image: API Json response]

Which I would like to map using the following paginator:

/* BBActivityPaginator */

```
RKObjectMapping *activityPaginationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[BBActivityPaginator class]];
[activityPaginationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"Page" :@"currentPage",
 @"PageSize" :@"perPage",
 @"TotalResultCount" :@"objectCount"
 }];
[activityPaginationMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"PagedListItems" toKeyPath:@"activities" withMapping:activityMapping]];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:activityPaginationMapping
                                                                       pathPattern:@"/?PageSize=:perPage&Page=:page"
                                                                           keyPath:@"Model.Activities"
                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
```

which is related to this mapping:

/* BBActivity */

```
RKObjectMapping *activityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[BBActivity class]];
[activityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"Id" :@"identifier",
    @"CreatedDateTime" :@"createdOn",
    @"Description" :@"description",
    @"CreatedDateTimeOrder" :@"order",
    @"Type" :@"type",
    @"DeletedActivityItem.Message" :@"deleted"
 }];
[activityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"User" toKeyPath:@"user" withMapping:userMapping]];
[activityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"ObservationAdded.Observation" toKeyPath:@"observation" withMapping:observationMapping]];
[activityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"SightingNoteAdded.SightingNote" toKeyPath:@"observationNote" withMapping:observationNoteMapping]];
[activityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"SightingNoteAdded.Sighting" toKeyPath:@"observationNoteObservation" withMapping:observationMapping]];
[activityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"IdentificationAdded.Sighting" toKeyPath:@"identificationObservation" withMapping:observationMapping]];
[activityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"IdentificationAdded.Identification" toKeyPath:@"identification" withMapping:identificationMapping]];
[activityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"PostAdded.Post" toKeyPath:@"post" withMapping:postMapping]];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:activityMapping
                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
```

... For brevity I won't add all the mappings...

When I want to make my call to the paginator, I'm wiring up this:

```
-(void)setPaginatorForStream:(NSString*)streamName {

    [BBLog Log:@"BBStreamController.setPaginatorForStream:"];
    [BBLog Debug:@"streamName:" withMessage:streamName];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;



        NSString *streamUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.blahblah.org.au/%@?PageSize=:perPage&Page=:currentPage&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest", streamName];


    if (!self.paginator) {

paginationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[BBActivityPaginator class]];

        RKResponseDescriptor *activitiesResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[BBActivityPaginator class]]
                                                                     pathPattern:nil
                                                                         keyPath:nil
                                                                     statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

        self.paginator = [[BBActivityPaginator alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:streamUrl]]
                                                   paginationMapping:paginationMapping
                                                 responseDescriptors:[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:activitiesResponseDescriptor, nil]
                                                         andDelegate:weakSelf];

    }

self.paginator.perPage = 20;

[self.paginator setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKPaginator *paginator, NSArray *objects, NSUInteger page) {
    [weakSelf.tableItems addObjectsFromArray:objects];
    [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];

} failure:^(RKPaginator *paginator, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
}];
```

Which is being activated in this method:

```
-(void)loadRequest {
    [BBLog Log:@"BBStreamController.loadRequest"];

    self.fetchBatch++;

    [self.paginator loadPage:self.fetchBatch];

    //[self.paginator setPaginatorLoading:YES];
    self.loading = YES;
}
```

from the class initialisation:

```
-(BBStreamController*)initWithGroup:(NSString*)groupIdentifier
                        andDelegate:(id<BBStreamProtocol>)delegate {
    [BBLog Log:@"BBStreamController.initWithGroup:andDelegate:"];

    self = [self init];

    if(self) {
        _controller = delegate;
        groupId = groupIdentifier;

        [self setPaginatorForStream:groupIdentifier];

        [self loadRequest];
    }

    [self loadView];

    return self;
}
```

And getting nothing but pain...

Output:

E restkit:RKPaginator.m:207 Paginator didn't map info to compute page count. Assuming no pages.
2013-05-06 17:48:09.487 BowerBird[26570:5807] W restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:98 Adding mapping error: No mappable values found for any of the attributes or relationship mappings

Any one familiar with the finer details of RestKit 0.2.x's new pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Your `pathPattern` and `keyPath` information needs to be set on the `activitiesResponseDescriptor` definition, not some paginator response descriptor that isn't actually used for anything.

The response descriptor is for the overall response and describes how to:

1. Tell that we have a match : `pathPattern`
2. Find the data to process : `keyPath`
3. Create the response objects : data mapping

The paginator mapping is additional to this and is **only** used to extract the page data from the response being processed.

Move the path pattern and key path to the response descriptor used for the request. The path pattern should also contain "PagedListItems" by the looks of it.

Comment: Hello again Wain... I've been meddling with this all day - thanks for answering. I'll give this a try.